# Multiline progress-bar bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to make a multiline `progress` bar in `bootstrap` like this:

```
[=============
==============
==============
=============]
```

(in the same progress bar div)

i've tried to tweak the overflow propriety, but it doesn't seems to work.

if you know how an other way to do this, tell me :

i have 5 percentages like 10%, 25%,  15%, 40%, 10%
And i want it to display it like :

```
<---10%--=====25%====
==--15%--========40%=  
=============--10%-->
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is Bootstrap 3  has a ton of helpers to speed up development. There's a few to choose from.Here's my pen

```
[http://www.bootply.com/cXz75zjS4a][1] 


[http://codepen.io/jbeurel/pen/zuDAl][1]

<div class="container">
  <h2>Colored Progress Bars</h2>
  <p>The contextual classes colors the progress bars:</p> 
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
      40% Complete (success)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
    40% Complete (success)
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:60%">
      60% Complete (warning)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
      70% Complete (danger)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```